# Ideals Generated by an Element

Tags: ring-theory

I was wondering if anyone could give me a little explanation into ideals and principal ideals.  I know that for $a \in R$, the ***principal ideal generated by $a$*** is the set

$$\langle a \rangle = \{r_1as_1+r_2as_2+ \ldots +r_nas_n \ | \ r_i, s_i \in R \}$$

What I don't unerstand is how we choose the $r_i, s_i$. For example, if in $\mathbb{Z}$ we were looking for the principal ideal generated by $8$, that is $\langle 8 \rangle$, how would we write this set? The source of the confusion is the following problem:

In $\mathbb{Z}$, show that $8$ belongs to the ideal generated by $10$ and $16$ but $\langle 8 \rangle \neq \langle 10, 16 \rangle$.

When it says "ideal generated by $10$ and $16$", is this the same as the *principal* ideal generated by $10$ and $16$? And what does it mean to write $\langle 10, 16 \rangle$? How do we construct the principal ideal generated by *two* elements? The general idea is really confusing me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The beginning's already odd: what's the relation between $\;A\,,\,R\;$ ? In general, for a ring $\;R\;$ , the principal (left, in case this matters, e.g. when the ring isn't commutative) ideal generated by $\;x\in R\;$ is the set $\;\langle x\rangle:=\{rx\;:\;r\in R\}\;$

Comment: This is another thing confusing me, in my notes I just have that the stated set $\langle a \rangle$ is an ideal which contains $a$ and is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $a$. Shouldn't we take $a \in R$ rather than in $A$?

Comment: the question makes no sense at all until we know what in the world is $\;A\;$ and what's its relation with the ring $\;R\;$ is !

Comment: I've edited it as I assume we must be taking $a \in R$, I can only assume it was a typo in the notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't unerstand is how we choose the $r_i$, $s_i$. For example, if in $\mathbb Z$ we were looking for the principal ideal generated by $8$, that is $\langle8\rangle$, how would we write this set?

In general the $r_i$ and $s_i$ may be any ring element, but in the case where the ambient ring $R$ is commutative – like $\mathbb Z$ – the definition of principal ideal may be considerably simplified.
$$
\langle a \rangle = \{ra\,:r\in R\}.
$$
I leave it as an exercise to you to prove that the definitions are equivalent in the commutative case. This means that $\langle8\rangle$ is simply the subset of $\mathbb Z$ consisting of multiples of $8$, such as $-16$, $0$, or $64$.

> When it says "ideal generated by 10 and 16", is this the same as the principal ideal generated by 10 and 16? And what does it mean to write $\langle10,16\rangle$? How do we construct the principal ideal generated by two elements?

For one, be careful with the phrase "a principal ideal generated by two elements". An ideal is *principal* by definition if it is generated by a single element. In certain rings, such as $\mathbb Z$, every ideal is principal, but most other rings (like $\mathbb Z[x]$) have nonprincipal ideals.

More generally, when $R$ is commutative we may write an ideal generated by finitely many elements as
$$
\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle = \{r_1a_1 + \cdots + r_na_n\,:\,r_i\in R\};
$$
in other words, the ideal consists of $R$-linear combinations of the $a_i$, in analogy with linear combinations of vectors in a vector space.
This means that $\langle10,16\rangle$ is the subset of $\mathbb Z$ consisting of $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of $10$ and $16$, such as $10$, $26$, and $6$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot of sense!

Comment: If $8 \in \langle 10,16 \rangle$, am I right in thinking that we require a solution to $10s+16r=8$ with $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ So, for example, $r=4, s=-2$? But then if $\langle 8 \rangle \neq \langle 10,16 \rangle$ wouldn't that mean we needed to show that there exists some $p \in \langle 8 \rangle$ that isn't contained in $\langle 10,16 \rangle$, i.e. there is a $p$ such that $10r+16s=8p$ has no ineteger solution? But $gcd(10,16)=2$ which divides all elements in $\langle 8 \rangle$...i'm clearly missing something here, could you perhaps enlighten me?

Comment: All that $\langle 8\rangle\neq\langle10,16\rangle$ means is that there is some element contained in $\langle 8\rangle$ but not $\langle10,16\rangle$, *or* that there is some element contained in $\langle10,16\rangle$ but not $\langle8\rangle$. You have shown that the first case is impossible; what about the second?